# Property set at one endpoint in the Camel Exchange is not available in another endpoint in the Camunda Workflow

Tags: apache-camel, camunda

I am calling a camel endpoint from the service task in a Camunda BPM workflow, and then an external HTTP request is sent to an endpoint and the response is saved as a property in the camel exchange, but the property is not propagated ?

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:preferredPaymentMethod")
            .log("PreferredPaymentMethodRoute")
            .bean(PreferredPaymentMethodTransformation.class, "transform")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("related.id=${in.headers.relatedId}"))
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .to("http4://localhost:9090/paymentMethods/v1/paymentMethod")
            .id("PreferredPaymentMethod-http")
            .unmarshal(jsonDataFormat)
            .convertBodyTo(PaymentMethodResponseBean.class)
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    Map<String, Object> preferredPaymentMethodResponse = new HashMap<>();
                    preferredPaymentMethodResponse.put("responseCode", exchange.getIn().getHeaders().get(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE));
                    preferredPaymentMethodResponse.put("response", exchange.getIn().getBody(PaymentMethodResponseBean.class));
                    exchange.setProperty("preferredPaymentMethodResponse", preferredPaymentMethodResponse);
                }
            })
            .bean(PreferredPaymentMethodTransformation.class, "processResponse")
            .id("PreferredPaymentMethod-processResponse")
            .routeId("PreferredPaymentMethodRoute");
}
```

I even tried setting the property in the bean method *processResponse*.

Comment: Where are you attempting to retrieve the property value?

Comment: @SneharghyaPathak The next service task in the workflow will send the exchange to an endpoint and I need to access the property there.